# Money formatting using rails-money gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, money-format

I'm trying to format money via money rails gem, but that doesnt seem to work as intended.

Here's what i have

```
pry(main)> Money.new(100, "USD").format(no_cents: true, symbol: nil)
=> "$1.00"
```

As you see formatting doesnt work at all. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: What you wrote works OK for me. It shows "1"

Comment: Could it be that your money gem version is outdated?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the money-rails [helpers](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#helpers):

> - get the money value without the cents part:
>   <%= money_without_cents @money_object %>
>
> This will render a formatted money value **without the currency symbol** and **without the cents part**.